# How can I create a display in views with different filter criteria

Tags: views

Can I have a view with different displays? I.e. I would like to have the same display twice but in the second one, I just want to have an additional filter criteria. How can I do this?

**edit 1**

I cloned my initial display and added a new filter to the new one. I selected "This page (override)" and selected "Content: Title (contains `Brunch`)" but, I hit save but it doesn't seem to apply the filter:http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/restaurant-specials (new display) vs.
http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/special-events (generic display)
Why is this, what did I do wrong?
The query looks correct:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS field_data_field_eventdate_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_table_description_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_link_to_page_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_eventdate} field_data_field_eventdate ON node.nid = field_data_field_eventdate.entity_id AND (field_data_field_eventdate.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_eventdate.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('event')) AND (node.title LIKE '%Brunch%' ESCAPE '\\') ))
ORDER BY field_data_field_eventdate.field_eventdate_value ASC
```

but doesn't seem to get applied...for the new display - and yes, I hot "save"!

**edit 2**

It seems like the "This page (override)" feature doesn't work properly, I changed the title of my restaurant display and it doesn't geta pplied either.. any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for filter criterias to be applied correctly to only one display,  multiple displays are required to have different names!

Answer (score 1):

You can clone your first display. In your second display you can add additional filters. Be sure when you add filters to choose to override from the dropdown menu, located at the top-left of your filter modal. This way, the additional filters are applied only to your second display.

Comment: please see **edit 1** above.

Comment: As far as I can see you aren't doing anything wrong in overriding page title or filters. Did you already cleared the caches (both Drupal & Views)? Perhaps you're still seeing the cached version of your pages.